# Getting the offsetWidth (or equivalent) of an LI element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to get the width of the element using jQuery.

```js
alert($("#theList li:eq(0)").offsetWidth);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="theList">
  <li>The quick brown fox
</ol>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery has `$(elem).width()` function that returns `offsetWidth` of element

```js
alert($("#theList li:eq(0)").width());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol id="theList">
  <li>The quick brown fox</li> <!--also you forgot closing tag -->
</ol>
```

Comment: jquery `.width()` only includes the content width. If you really want an equivalent to `.offsetWidth` you need to use jquery `.outerWidth()`

Comment: Neither of them equivalent to offsetWidth. If the element is hidden (for example, by setting style.display on the element or one of its ancestors to "none"), offsetWidth returns 0.

Answer (score 5):

You're mixing jQuery and standard Javascript together incorrectly.

To use .outerWidth you need to access the DOM element:

```
alert($("#theList li:eq(0)")[0].offsetWidth);
```

Or you could go with jQuery's [.outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/):

```
alert($("#theList li:eq(0)").outerWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

[offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) is a Readonly property of HTML Element. So you should use this mechanism to first get the first element of the selection which will then give you the HTMLElement of the jQuery selection and then get it attribute:

```
   $('#theList li:eq(0)')[0].offsetWidth
```